# API Platform validation before deserialization

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

My entity looks like this:

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\DateTime
     */
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $billingDateTime;

    public function getBillingDateTime(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->billingDateTime;
    }

    public function setBillingDateTime(?\DateTimeImmutable $billingDateTime): self
    {
        $this->billingDateTime = $billingDateTime;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I want the billing date time input string to be validated as DateTime with the default format "Y-m-d H:i:s". However, the validation happens after deserialization. So the input is parsed to a DateTimeImmutable object even if the input is in an invalid format.

Is there a way to validate the input string before deserialization happens?

Comment: Did you look here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/#validating-submitted-data ?

Comment: Not really. Validation phase happens after the deserialization completes (or after the form is bound to the object). You probably have to create a DTO where validation could be executed safely. Api platform is not very good with them, but could solve your problem. If you are interested, take a look on the project I just released (https://solid-o.github.io/docs/) which is an alternative to Api platform with better support for DTOs.

Comment: If you decorate \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer you can validate before passing the value to the decorated DateTimeNormalizer.